# Print Job Alternative

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

Do we have another class or component that can replace the print job class? Like it will capture the UI/Layout then print/write(as file/image)? Any ideas or alternatives would be much appreciated. Thanks and have a great day.

Cheers,
Glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlivePDF (alivepdf.bytearray.org/)  is an open source library for producing .pdf files from actionscript.  I have used it to print graphs and reports with much success.